# vscode python autocomplete setup

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have read and searched quite lot. All the discussions I have read about setting vscode to autocomplete on external (non-pip installed) modules say adding the directory of the modules in question to the user or workspace settings.json should make autocomplete available.

AFAIKT there is more to it, since nothing I've tried so far seems to work.

I have this in the workspace file:

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "/home/mac/freecad-build",
    "/home/mac/freecad-build/Mod/Part"]
```

And in the user I have this:

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "/home/mac/freecad-build/Mod/Draft",
    "/home/mac/freecad-build/lib",
    "/home/mac/freecad-build/Mod/Part",
    "/home/mac/freecad-build/Mod/Sketcher",
    "/home/mac/freecad-build/Mod/Mesh",
    "/home/mac/freecad-build/Mod/Drawing",
    "/home/mac/freecad-build/Mod/MeshPart"
]
```

Module import seems to be ok.
So this is ok:

```
import Part
```

But, when I type:

```
Part.
```

It throws this error:

Expected member name after "."

What am I missing?